# Finding strings that are matched by a given regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm trying to be ahead of the game by studying some Theory of Computation concepts before class starts at the end of this month.  There's this question I came across that I don't understand below.

```
Let L be the language defined by the regular expression:
(c U ab U b)*bb(c U ab)

(U = union)

A.  Write 10 distinct strings that belong to L.  
    If such strings don't exist, explain why.

B.  Write 10 distinct strings over alphabet {a,b,c} that don't belong to L.  
    If such strings don't exist, explain why.
```

---

I'm totally lost, I have the answer but I just don't get how to go about it.

The only answers that I've came up with, that belong to L, was:

```
bbc, bbab
```

Which's only 2 correct out of the 10 listed in the answer key.  I just can't see how to come about the rest of them.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: Do you understand regular expression notation? Why don't you use the part before `bb` to generate more strings?

Comment: @adrianN Thanks for your response. Here are some of the answers I came up with, since it says distinct strings. Tell me if they could be right: 
3.  `cabb`
4.  `cccccab`
5.  `cababca`
6.  `abcbbb`
7.  `ccbabb`
8.  `abbcb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the regular expression $(c \cup ab \cup b)^*bb(c \cup ab)$. It has three parts $(c \cup ab \cup b)^*$, $bb$, and $(c \cup ab)$. The first part means "zero or more repetitions of $(c \cup ab \cup b)$", the second part matches two $b$, and the third part matches $c$ or $ab$.

As you already mentioned in your question bbc and bbab are strings that are matched. In both we choose zero repetition of the first part then the obligatory bb and then c, respectively ab, to match the third part. To make this easier to see I'll separate the parts of the string that are matched by the different parts of the expression with a - like so: -bb-c and -bb-ab.

We can generate more strings by choosing more than zero repetitions of the first part. For example we can choose one repetition of c to get c-bb-c. c-bb-ab would also be ok. We could also choose more repetitions of c or a c followed by ab for the first part. So cc-bb-c and cab-bb-c would also be acceptable strings.

Comment: Thanks :).  Does this mean I can make any combination of strings within `(c U ab U b)*`, right?  Since the star represents strings that are >= 0?

Comment: Yes. You can choose zero or more times one of c, ab, or b.